# MySQL: BETWEEN A100000 and A200000

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to figure out the best way to be able to execute a  `BETWEEN` query, but be able to strip out a letter from the cell ... The column consists of a serial number like `V123456`, and obviously `BETWEEN` doesn't do well with letters.

Is there a way that I can essentially ignore the first character of the serial and run my `BETWEEN` statement on that?

```
Get me all records between V100000 and V100050
```

Comment: Are the records in the db stores as numbers or do they include the V as well?

Comment: Is this question still opened? Have you resolved your issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE data BETWEEN 'variable1' AND 'variable2'
```

Try that, if it does not work, let me know.

So for you:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE serial BETWEEN 'V123456' AND 'V123466'
```

This will work as long as your letter at the beginning is the same.  This worked for me on my local server as a test.  I have Col1 as ID, Col2 as serial.  I insert 7 variables (V10000 - V10007) and ran a script to get all serials between V10002 and V10005, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select * from records_table where serial >= "V100000" and serial <= "V150000"
```

Answer (score 0):

I made the following test:

```
create table test(

 searchfield varchar(100)

);

insert into test values('V100');
insert into test values('V101');
insert into test values('V102');
insert into test values('V103');
insert into test values('V104');
insert into test values('V105');
insert into test values('V106');
insert into test values('V107');
insert into test values('V108');
insert into test values('V109');
insert into test values('V110');
```

Tested query:

```
select * from test t 
where substring(t.searchfield,2) between 103 and 105;
```

Sqlfiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b5ecc/7